# How to log into one website then go to other websites without login?

Tags: authentication, httpcookie

Our business has multiple websites. How do I achieve this goal: Have one central website, once user logs into that website, he can click links to other websites without having to login on other websites?

Can I simply insert an encrypted cookie after user logs in on the central website, and have all other websites to check for this cookie?

Or are there more elaborate technologies?

Comment: Read on "SSO".  For example, here: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply. I will have a good read. But it sounds very elaborate and relying on third party services. Can I simply insert an encrypted cookie after user logs in on the central website, and have all other websites to check for this cookie? What are the risk of such an extremely simple solution?

Comment: I worked out why simple cookies wouldn't work: the cookies inserted by "www.mysite.com" is invisible to "www.myothersite.com".